# Rebuild a binary tree from pre--order and min-order transverse sequence, error in re-build procedure

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

The input is preOrder:BCAD  and  midOrder: CBAD，   but there is error in the recursive build function. If my guess is right, the while body can't jump out due to certain error, but I have no idea what the error exactly is.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char data;

    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(char d=0, Node* l=NULL, Node* r=NULL):data(d),left(l),right(r) {}
};

void recoverTree(char* pre, char* mid, Node* root);
void postTranverse(Node* root);
void clean(Node* root);

int main()
{
    char preArr[27], midArr[27];
    while(cin>>preArr>>midArr)
    {
        Node* root;
        recoverTree(preArr,midArr,root);
        postTranverse(root);

        clean(root);
    }

    return 0;
}

void recoverTree(char* pre, char* mid, Node* root)//build binary tree from given sequence
{
    char* midTemp=mid;
    if(*mid==0)
    {
        root=NULL;
        return;
    }

    while(true)     //loop can't jump out
    {
        if(*pre==*midTemp)
        {
            root=new Node(*pre);
            *midTemp=0;     //how to mark to stop the recursion, wrong?
            break;
        }
        ++midTemp;
    }

    recoverTree(pre+1,mid,root->left);
    recoverTree(pre+1,midTemp+1,root->right);
}

void postTranverse(Node* root)// post tranverse the tree
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    //if(root->left!=NULL)
        postTranverse(root->left);
    //if(root->right!=NULL)
        postTranverse(root->right);
    cout<<root->data;
}

void clean(Node* root)  //release memory in heap
{
    if(root->left!=NULL)
            clean(root->left);
    if(root->right!=NULL)
            clean(root->right);

    delete root;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "there is an error"? A build error? A runtime error or crash? Unexpected results? Please clarify.

Comment: Then you should run in a debugger to catch the "crash", and see where it happens in your code, and examine the variables to see if you can figure it out yourself. If not, then at least please edit your question to tell us where the crash happens, and what the values of all involved variables are.